# If $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is real, show that $\frac{1}{1-z}= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + i\cot(\theta/2)\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Question.**<sup>[(source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kIFY.jpg)</sup> If $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is real, show that
> $$\frac{1}{1-z}= \frac{1}{2}\left( 1+ i\cot\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

I have been trying to rearrange the right-hand-side in order to make it look like the required form, but have been struggling to do so and want to see if anyone is able to show me what steps need to be taken to solve this question.

Comment: Perhaps start from the LHS and rationalize it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: the half-angle identities
$$\cot(x/2)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$
or
$$\cot(x/2)=\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$
might turn out to be key for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the expression, using the exponential notation:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-z}&= \frac{1}{1-\mathrm e^{i\theta}}= \frac{1-\mathrm e^{-i\theta}}{(1-\mathrm e^{i\theta})(1-\mathrm e^{-i\theta})}\\
&= \frac{1-\mathrm e^{-i\theta}}{(2-\mathrm e^{i\theta}-\mathrm e^{-i\theta})}
== \frac{1-\mathrm e^{-i\theta}}{2(1-\cos\theta)}\\
&=\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)}+i\,\frac{\sin\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)}
\end{align}
continue with the duplication formulæ.

Comment: when i do this, I get 1/2 + i cot(x/2) but there is an extra 1/2 being multiplied by the cot(x/2), I do not know what to do about that

Comment: @newm I believe the question includes a typo. Note (for example) that $\frac{1}{1-i} = \tfrac12 + \tfrac12i$.

Comment: @newm:  Yes, the correct formula should be $\frac12\bigl(1+\cot\frac\theta 2\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun trick I learned when I saw this question for the first time.

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}} = \frac{e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{-i\theta/2} - e^{i\theta/2}} = \frac{\cos\tfrac12\theta - \sin\tfrac12\theta}{-2i\sin\tfrac12\theta} = \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{-2}{e^{i\theta}-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{e^{i\theta}-1-(e^{i\theta}+1)}{e^{i\theta}-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\times \left(1-\frac{e^{i\theta}+1}{e^{i\theta}-1}\right)$$
Note that $e^{i\theta}+1=e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}\cdot 2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$ and $e^{i\theta}-1=e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}\cdot 2i\sin (\frac{\theta}{2})$.

Plug in these results above,
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}=\frac{1}{2}\times \left(1-\frac{\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})}{i}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\times \left(1-\frac{i\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})}{i^2}\right)$$

$$\fbox{$\huge{\dfrac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}=\frac{1}{2}\times \left(1+i\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)}$}$$

I used some results above. See how I got it below.

$$e^{i\theta}+1=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta+1$$

$$=2\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}-1+2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \times \cos\frac{\theta}{2}+1$$

$$=2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}$$

The other result:

$$e^{i\theta}-1=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta-1$$

$$=1-2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}+2i\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{\theta}{2}-1$$

$$=2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\left(\frac{-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{i}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

$$=2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}$$